# How can I see the date/time on my apache server via ssh?

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server

Is there a function I can run at the command line (with ssh access) to see the date and time that's set on my apache server?

Comment: Apache is in application that can be run on many different operating systems. The operating system is what is important in this question. The Apache HTTP server is pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can usually use `date`, that should be available on most (if not all) *nix OSes.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your Apache server is running Linux (or some other Unix-like OS), the `date` command will show the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date("H:i:s d/m/y", time());`
to get the time stamp for current time